# Stripe schedule subscription NodeJs

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payment, subscription

I have a problem with schedule subscription.
I need update subscription plan after end of period current subscription, but quantity of subscription items(phases) may be updated also. How can I do this?

I used subscription scheduled, but it doesn't work, phases quatity is so big, and i have exception when i've tried to add more then 15 objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't very clear here, but I think I understand.

Subscription Schedules have a limit of 10 phases.

If you need more, you'll need to wait for phases to complete before you can update the Schedule and add more.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/update?lang=node
When you do so, you can omit any past phases, but you'll need to set due ones again.